# nginx - not to redirect to https

Tags: django, nginx

Im trying to setup nginx as a proxy server for my django server and here is my configuration.

For some reason when I send a request to the server http://ipaddress it automatically redirects me to https://ipaddress even though I have included anything to redirect.
I want to disable the redirect to https as its a dev server

```
upstream app_server {
        # For a TCP configuration:
        server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    }
# configuration of the server
server {
    #add_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80 default_server;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    charset     utf-8;
    #server_name localhost;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass   http://app_server;
        }   
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your configuration that would do that. Maybe the django service is returning the redirect.

Comment: you were right..thanks.I have to disable django sslify---https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify